# Facebook Like Box iFrame no longer displaying on website

Tags: facebook, iframe

Our client's website http://www.chantre.com used to have their Facebook Like Box displayed on the left side of their site (directly under "NY/NJ Listing"). Two things have occurred/I noticed today:

1. I created an app in our developers account and used the free hosting option so I could generate secure URLs. I subsequently have removed the app in both the FB Developers area, and the Heroku hosting environment;

It seems that since I did this the Like Box no longer displays.

1. If I regenerate the Like Box which creates the following iFrame code, the Like Box won't display:

If I paste the URL into Chrome or Safari I see the feed properly, as well as when I do the actual Like Box setup in Facebook, however no such luck in IE or Firefox. I thought that both Chrome and Safari were cached, but all history and cache has been cleared.

Can anyone shed some light on this, it would be great. I'm sure my client will notice this pretty soon and I'd like to fix it asap.

If you go to the page on their site, you can see a commented out iFrame that does display properly. I'm wondering if I need to recreate an app in Developers, but unsure what to select.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/davisrchantrealtors, the page that you set the href of the like box to, is not available for me. Is that the correct page name? Is it restricted in any way (age, country, alcohol)?

Comment: Try to access it now. I removed the US and 18 years or older restriction.

Comment: … and now magically the like box on your site works again ;-)

Comment: Very odd. I just visited the page again, the Like Box is displaying. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah I see :) THANKS!!!! Lifesaver

Comment: I'd like to give you credit for the correct answer, but since this is only a comment I am unable to do so. Please answer the question and I'll be sure to accept it. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

facebook.com/davisrchantrealtors, the page that you set the href of the like box to, is not available for me. Is that the correct page name? Is it restricted in any way (age, country, alcohol)?

[and after correcting settings]

… and now magically the like box on your site works again ;-)